# First Reply on Ping is Unreachable the rest is okay

Tags: ip, ping, arp, ipv4

please check this weird ping i'm having

What may have caused this problem

Comment: Is the host your pinging from 192.168.22.1?

Comment: So you're pinging your own ip address?

Comment: I asked you if the machine you were pinging **FROM** was 192.168.22.1 and you said no. You said the ip address you're pinging **FROM** is 192.168.22.181. I'm not understanding you. What is the ip address of the machine you're pinging **FROM**?

Comment: Oh i'm sorry im pinging from 192.168.5.215

Comment: I might be able to answer this question if you update it with the IP address and netmask of each network interface on the path between the two hosts.

Answer (score 3):

The first ping that times out is typically your gateway creating an ARP entry for the port address.

If you make no changes, and immediately ping the same address again, do you still get the first ping to time out?   If yes, then try to 'ping 192.168.22.181 -c 30' and see if you get any time outs in the 30 ping reqeusts that get sent out.

Comment: Hi if I immediately make another ping request to the same IP, I don't get the timeout, however if I wait for a certain amount of time it will be having the same issue of an unreachable host

Comment: That's perfectly normal. The ARP cache is transient. The ARP cache entries will "age out" and once they do, the ip address will have to be resolved to the MAC address again, which will generate the `Destination host unreachable` message.